# Check if array inside the tuple is empty in Python

Tags: python

In my code I have a line, which looks for values set to 1 in `numpy.ndarray` type:

`neg_samples = np.where(Y1[0, :, -1] == 1)`

and it returns using `print(neg_samples)` such tuple:

`(array([ 0,  1,  2]),)`

but sometimes the array is empty and the result is as following:

`(array([], dtype=int64),)`

I need to check if this array is empty or not. I tried with:

```py
   if len(neg_samples) > 0:
       neg_samples = neg_samples[0]
   else:
       neg_samples = []
```

But each time, everytime it goes just on, so I decided to check the length of this `neg_samples` and it looks like everytime, whenever it's `(array([], dtype=int64),)` or `(array([ 0,  1,  2(...), 199, 200]),)` it's always `len(neg_samples)=1`.

Using `if not all(neg_samples):` throws

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.`

I think the problem is that array is inside the tuple. How can I check if this array inside this tuple is empty or not?

Comment: `if len(neg_samples[0]) > 0`? Just look at the first item in the tuple, which is the array you're interested in?

Comment: Hmm, sounds reasonable, I'll check it

Comment: I don't know the exact purpose of your code but often more elegant solutions may be obtained by just using `V1 == 1` (or `V1[0, :, -1] == 1`)

Comment: @AndreiBoyanov it's a code for implementation Faster RCNN algorithm, I downloaded it and I'm trying to understand how it's implemented and how it's working. I got several errors during running it, so Im debugging and fixing to work :) so for now I don't want to edit some parts of the code, as I don't know if I will refactor it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [54]: a = (array.array('d', []),)

In [55]: len(a)
Out[55]: 1

In [56]: len(a[0])
Out[56]: 0
```

check the len before proceeding further

Comment: Thanks, combining @Green Cloack Guy's comment and your approach I made it! :)